# How to Gather & Parse JSON Data in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, drupal-8

I'm ultimately looking to create a HTML file that will accomplish the following tasks.  The point is, I need it to be all inclusive in an HTML snippet/file.

1. Make a GET api call to a backend CMS (ie:  Drupal). This api call returns the following JSON data for a specific content item:

```js
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "meta": {
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "node--espot_html",
        "id": "fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45",
        "attributes": {
            "drupal_internal__nid": 1,
            "drupal_internal__vid": 11,
            "langcode": "en",
            "revision_timestamp": "2019-10-31T13:29:29+00:00",
            "revision_log": null,
            "status": true,
            "title": "Razor Hero Image",
            "created": "2019-10-28T16:24:20+00:00",
            "changed": "2019-10-31T13:29:29+00:00",
            "promote": true,
            "sticky": false,
            "default_langcode": true,
            "revision_translation_affected": true,
            "path": {
                "alias": "/razor-hero",
                "pid": 1,
                "langcode": "en"
            },
            "body": {
                "value": "<div class=\"jns-hero-image jns-hero-image-message-left\" id=\"hero_slideshow\"><img alt=\"Clean Shave\" data-entity-type=\"file\" data-entity-uuid=\"fbc875d0-ef17-4813-981c-22a29e42c44f\" src=\"/sites/default/files/inline-images/dont-shave-2.jpg\" />\r\n<div class=\"grid-container\">\r\n<div class=\"grid-x grid-padding-x\">\r\n<div class=\"small-12 medium-8 cell hero-message\">\r\n<div>\r\n<h1 class=\"text-hero text-hero-left\">Get a Much Better<br />\r\nShave</h1>\r\n\r\n<p>Fewer things look and feel better than a clean shave!</p>\r\n<a>SHOP NOW</a></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n",
                "format": "full_html",
                "processed": "<div class=\"jns-hero-image jns-hero-image-message-left\" id=\"hero_slideshow\"><img alt=\"Clean Shave\" data-entity-type=\"file\" data-entity-uuid=\"fbc875d0-ef17-4813-981c-22a29e42c44f\" src=\"/sites/default/files/inline-images/dont-shave-2.jpg\" /><div class=\"grid-container\">\n<div class=\"grid-x grid-padding-x\">\n<div class=\"small-12 medium-8 cell hero-message\">\n<div>\n<h1 class=\"text-hero text-hero-left\">Get a Much Better<br />\nShave</h1>\n\n<p>Fewer things look and feel better than a clean shave!</p>\n<a>SHOP NOW</a></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n",
                "summary": ""
            }
        },
        "relationships": {
            "node_type": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "node_type--node_type",
                    "id": "837a5cbe-f8fe-4c03-a613-2092dff1168e"
                },
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45/relationships/node_type?resourceVersion=id%3A11"
                    },
                    "related": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45/node_type?resourceVersion=id%3A11"
                    }
                }
            },
            "revision_uid": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "user--user",
                    "id": "c0d80edb-325a-4ad7-9be3-bc9dc32ed878"
                },
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45/relationships/revision_uid?resourceVersion=id%3A11"
                    },
                    "related": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45/revision_uid?resourceVersion=id%3A11"
                    }
                }
            },
            "uid": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "user--user",
                    "id": "c0d80edb-325a-4ad7-9be3-bc9dc32ed878"
                },
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45/relationships/uid?resourceVersion=id%3A11"
                    },
                    "related": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45/uid?resourceVersion=id%3A11"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45?resourceVersion=id%3A11"
            }
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45"
        }
    }
}
```

2. I'm then looking for the JSON response to be parsed to extract the only the data under the "value": object.
3. I need to have the escape characters removed
4. The end result should be that the HTML (shown below) is rendered in the browser:

```html
<div class="jns-hero-image jns-hero-image-message-left" id="hero_slideshow"><img alt="Clean Shave" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="fbc875d0-ef17-4813-981c-22a29e42c44f" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/dont-shave-2.jpg" /><div class="grid-container"><div class="grid-x grid-padding-x"><div class="small-12 medium-8 cell hero-message"><div><h1 class="text-hero text-hero-left">Get a Much Better<br />Shave</h1><p>Fewer things look and feel better than a clean shave!</p><a>SHOP NOW</a></div></div></div></div></div>"
```

5. If processed successfully, this is what should display on the webpage:
   [Screenshot if image rendered via HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hKzU.png)
6. Here is the HTML I have tried.  My apologies for breaking etiquette, I was not aware this would be perceived as such.  In my browsers console it tells me the forEach is not a valid function or this response.

```html
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Ghibli App</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
  </head>
 

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
     <script>
  const app = document.getElementById('root');

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

app.appendChild(logo);
app.appendChild(container);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45', true);
request.onload = function () {

 // Begin accessing JSON data here
 var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
 if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
   data.forEach(value => {
     const card = document.createElement('div');
     card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

     const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
     h1.textContent = valuable.title;

     const p = document.createElement('p');
     value.description = value.description.substring(0, 300);
     p.textContent = `${value.description}...`;

     container.appendChild(card);
     card.appendChild(h1);
     card.appendChild(p);
   });
 } else {
   const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
   errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`;
   app.appendChild(errorMessage);
 }
}

request.send();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>'
```

Comment: So, you're very clear on what you want, which is great. What's not clear is what you've tried to do yourself. While the volunteers who answer questions on Stack Overflow could probably spend the time needed to create the application you want, it seems kind of disrespectful to ask them to do so. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to find out what makes for an enjoyable experience on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you try with `responseText` instead of `response` for your data, since you're not setting the JSON datatype. `var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);`?

Comment: this is what the console shows when I load it in the browser:
json_backup.html:31 Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload

Answer (score 1):

This ended up producing the end result that I was looking to produce:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>
const app = document.getElementById('root');

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  
    let obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
 console.log(obj.data.attributes.body.value)
 app.innerHTML = obj.data.attributes.body.value.replace('src="/sites','src="http://localhost:4700/sites'); 
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45", true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```